# Find the local truncation error (LTE) of $y'=e^{t-y}$ using Euler's Method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eulers-method, truncation-error

Find the local truncation error (LTE) of $y'=e^{t-y}$ using Euler's Method, knowing that $y(0)=1$, $t=[0,1]$, $h=0.25$

I know the local truncation error (LTE) introduced by the Euler method is given by the difference between the numerical solution by the exact solution, in other words $e_{i}=|y_{i}-y_{t_{i}}|$, but I do not know exactly how to manipulate the values. I would like to have this exercise as an example for me to understand the steps better.

I have got to the values of $y_{i}$: $(0,1);(0.25,1.0920); (0.5,1.1997);(0.75,1.3239); (1,1.4647)$

Comment: The equation is separable, you can easily find the exact solution. Note that the local truncation error is the error in a single step, so you need exact solutions for every point of the numerical solution to get the local error at the next point.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34191432/matlab-converting-euler-method-to-heuns-method/53997510#53997510 to confirm also visually that there is a difference between local and global error.

Comment: this link is all coded. it would help if it was literal. (i cant compile)

Comment: You could translate to the CAS or Matlab-like environment that you have at disposal, in this case even a spreadsheet would work. A minimal installation of octave will also run most of the educational Matlab examples. Many Matlab examples can be translated almost line-to-line. // But the message of the link was that there is a very noticeable difference between global error and local truncation error. Your $e_i$ are wrong as local errors, they are global errors, the difference of the numerical approximation to the exact solution of the original IVP.

Answer (score 1):

If $y(t)=\phi(t;t_o,y_o)$ is the flow function, where varying the first argument gives the solution $y$ for the IVP with $y(t_o)=y_o$, then the local truncation error along the numerical solution is
$$
\tau_i=\frac{|y_{i+1}-\phi(t_{i+1};t_i,y_i)|}{h}=\left|\frac{\phi(t_i+h;t_i,y_i)-y_i}{h}-f(t_i,y_i)\right|
$$
As the equation is separable, one can directly integrate
$$
e^y-e^t=e^{y_o}-e^{t_o}\implies \phi(t;t_o,y_o)=\ln(e^{y_o}+e^t-e^{t_o})
$$
This makes a direct computation of the truncation errors easily possible.